# Size of array when passed to a function

Tags: c, arrays

Can anyone explain me the output of the below program?

```
   #define SIZE 10
  void size(int arr[SIZE],int i[SIZE])
  {
         printf("size of array is:%d %d\n",sizeof(arr),sizeof(i));
  }

  int main()
    {
        int arr[SIZE],i[SIZE];
       printf("%d %d\n",sizeof(arr),sizeof(i));
        size(arr,i);
        return 0;
     }                                                                                

      OUTPUT
      40 40 
     8 8
```

why 8 8?
plz help

Answer (score 2):

Because the arguments `int arr[SIZE]` and `int i[SIZE]` are not arrays like they were in the `main` function.  They are *pointers*.  And pointers generally have size 8 on 64-bit machines.

Comment: @CodeHacker If it was 8 the first time that it ran on your machine, then it will continue to alway be 8.  But on another computer, it might be different.

Answer (score 2):

1. In `main()` you are getting size of array.
2. When we call `size(arr, i);`, we are sending the base address of  `arr` and `i`. When we pass address of a variable to a function, it will store the address in a pointer. So you are getting the size of pointer in your `size()` function.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Yes you are right they are not same! I have made an edit. Thanks for pointing it out :)
`arr` gives the address of first int, whereas `&arr` gives the address of array of _ints_.

Also `arr+1` will give the address of the next integer, whereas `&arr+1` will give the address of next array of `10` integers.

Answer (score -2):

Arrays themselves substituted to pointers (but they are not pointer, however). So, code

```
a[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
*(a + i)
```

When array is not dynamic, sizeof operator can determine it's size (within it's scope), but when it is passed to function it is a pointer. So

```
sizeof(any_pointer) == sizeof(size_t)
```

due to result, seems you work on 64-bit processor

Comment: `sizeof(any_pointer) == sizeof(size_t)` - do you mean to say that this is always true? because it isn't...

Comment: Not any pointer, but without any other circumstances... Can you make example where pointer is not tiny, huge, etc. and it is not size_t; I am really interested.

Comment: then, how is it relevant to the question? OP is not asking anything about the size of `size_t`.

Comment: He asked about 8 bytes. Why 10*sizeof(int) == 40 and pointer is 8

Comment: Yes, he did. There's therefore no need to bring `sizeof(size_t)` into the picture -- it will only confuse OP.

Comment: Why it will confuse? And when pointer is not size_t?

Comment: when i give array size as array[10]. it assigns array from 0 to 10 So why it is not 44 bytes??

Comment: @CodeHacker first, that's 0 to 9, so at most 40 would be acceptable. And it's not an array but a pointer *because the C specification says so.*

Comment: arr points to the beginning of array. sizeof(arr) returns within scope it's size (number of elements multiply sizeof(element)). When you call function address of first element of array is passed.

Comment: @IvanIvanov I used a system once where `size_t` was 16 bits and `void *` was 17 bits

Comment: size_t. A basic unsigned integer C/C++ type. It is the type of the result returned by sizeof operator. The type's size is chosen so that it could store the maximum size of a theoretically possible array of any type. On a 32-bit system size_t will take 32 bits and on a 64-bit one - 64 bits. In other words, a pointer can be safely put inside size_t type (an exception is class-function-pointers but this is a special case). That is only thing I believe in, I mean I am wrong, 17 bit is nice and so on, but for me that is frustrating.